# How do you choose the last string in a String value?

Tags: string, post

There are two tables:

```
Student(sid integer, sname varchar(20), programme varchar(4), level integer, age integer)
Tutor(tid integer, tname varchar(20))
```

The task is to find the names of all IT students who are enrolled in a class taught by a tutor whose surname is Hoffman.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT s.sname
FROM student s, tutor t
WHERE s.programme = 'IT' AND t.tname = '%Hoffman';
```

However, the '%Hoffman' part will only search for a string which contains 'Hoffman', so technically if if there would be anyone with Hoffman as the first name, the query will return his data too.

The tname column is of type String and consist of a first name, a space, and a last name, and possible middle names in between.

How do you choose the last string (or index?) of a value in t.tname in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

WHERE s.programme = 'IT' and RIGHT(t.tname, 7)

since 'Hoffman' has 7 characters

Comment: or you could also just use the tutor's id of the tutor's name